# Updating customer group from observer on customer_register_success event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-group

I want to set a customer group as first time user for that I am using an observer so that I can update the customer group just after or on the same time of registration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First create your configuration file in `Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="persistent" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create the observer `Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCustomerGroupId implements ObserverInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID = 2;

    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) {
            $customer->setGroupId(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID);
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);;
        }
    }
}
```

NB: don't forget to replace `2` with the id of the customer group you want to use.

Comment: hey thanks a tonn can u tell me how to update with general group to this custom customer group.?

Comment: @supriyamishra what is your general group id ?

Comment: for general it is 1, which is by default , i want it to get updated just after registration by 7.

Comment: I replaced 2 by 7 in your code too

Comment: @supriyamishra I've updated my code so it only updates the customer with group = general to the new custom group with id = 7

Comment: not updating :(

Comment: @supriyamishra is the observer called at all ?

Comment: nope! i did logger its not called

Comment: @supriyamishra check the file name and path it works for me

Comment: Yeah Got it file name was misstyped

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::save() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\PinkBlue\InviteApi\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId.php on line 26

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47926/discussion-between-supriya-mishra-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Comment: @supriyamishra see my updated answer

Comment: What about the guest users who later registers after order placement?

Comment: hi @ i have tried with your code but my observer could not be trigger can u suggest me alternative just i want to save value to customer attribute when registered success

Comment: did you found the solution

Comment: Shall i assign a guest order tho the customer using the above event what u have mentioned