# Magento 2.2.2 How to set/save customer group in backend?

Tags: magento2, customer, registration

I have set the customer group in the frontend on customer signup form. When we create an account all the fields are saved and the customer group is saved i.e General. When we choose the customer group to be Retailer. I the backend its shows the General.

How to save the customer group in backend???

**See the Screenshot:**
https://prnt.sc/jthrui

Comment: you have to set customer group from observer, follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143952/20064)

Comment: Error is shown i.e "Group" is a required value.